# Not able to set the default value in the select box using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to set a default value to the select box's options using ng-init in angular js but it isn't working. Here's the code that I have written so far.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])

app.controller("mainController", ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.myoptions = "";
    $scope.mainList = [
      "firstOption",
      "secondOption",
      "thirdOption"
    ]
}]);
```

```css
select{
width:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<select ng-controller="mainController" ng-options="options as options for options in mainList" ng-model="myoptions" nginit="myoptions=mainList[1]">
</select>
</body>
```

Please help me with it. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Change `nginit` to `ng-init`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be `ng-init` there is no `nginit` directive in angular js

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])

app.controller("mainController", ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.myoptions = "";
    $scope.mainList = [
      "firstOption",
      "secondOption",
      "thirdOption"
    ]
}]);
```

```css
select{
width:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<select ng-controller="mainController" ng-options="options as options for options in mainList" ng-model="myoptions" ng-init="myoptions=mainList[1]">
</select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

you have

```
nginit
```

which should be

```
ng-init
```

Answer (score 2):

`ng-init="myoptions=mainList[0]"`

Answer (score 1):

change `nginit="myoptions = mainList[1]"`

to `ng-init="myoptions = mainList[1]"`

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])

app.controller("mainController", ["$scope", function($scope){
    
    $scope.mainList = [
      "firstOption",
      "secondOption",
      "thirdOption"
    ]
     
}]);
```

```css
select{
width:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<select ng-controller="mainController" ng-options="options as options for options in mainList" ng-model="myoptions" ng-init="myoptions = mainList[1]">
</select>
</body>
```